# make a balance command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a betting game for my bot and I want to add a currency but I have no idea on how to do it. Would I need to open a txt file and list out all members names? any help would be great thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can store peoples balances by using a JSON file with dicts or using a database. You just store it with peoples id’s. If you don’t know anything about JSON or databases just google it. Then when you run a balance command it looks for their balance by their user id and returns the data. I can go more in depth if needed just let me know